# Get Raster Catalog Names from a File Geodatabase Programmatically

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-9.3, raster-catalog

I'm trying to get only raster catalog entries from a file geodatabase using the `arcgisscripting` geoprocessing API. So far I am able to do this using the [`ListDatasets`](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgiSDEsktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=ListDatasets_method) function using the `ALL` argument. The problem is that it also returns raster datasets as well and I suspect there are other types it would return if they were present in the file geodatabase. I've tried the `Raster` argument but it returns the raster datasets and omits the raster catalogs. I guess I could filter the items returned from `gp.ListDatasets("", "Raster")` from the items returned from `gp.ListDatasets("", "ALL")` leaving me with what I'm looking for, however there might be some other type I don't know of that would be left in the list if it were present.

Here is the code I'm starting with:

```
import arcgisscripting
gp = arcgisscripting.create(9.3)
gp.workspace = r"C:\FileGeodatabase"
datasets = gp.ListDatasets("", "ALL")
for dataset in dataset:
    #Only want raster catalogs here...
```

I'm looking for a way to get **only** raster catalogs. What approach would ensure I'm working only with raster catalogs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the [RasterCatalog](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000v0000001m000000) feature_type argument:

```
datasetList = arcpy.ListDatasets("C*", "RasterCatalog")

for dataset in datasetList:
    print dataset
```

**EDIT:**

OK, above won't work on 9.3, so what about getting the DatasetType of each object and if it is of type RasterCatalog, then list it (below code untested)?

```
datasets = gp.ListDatasets("", "ALL")
for dataset in datasets:
    desc = gp.Describe(dataset)
    if desc.DatasetType == "RasterCatalog":
        # do your thang
```

Here's a fancier workaround for 9.3 using a list comprehension:

```
cats = [c for c in gp.ListDatasets() 
        if gp.Describe(c).DatasetType == "RasterCatalog"]
```

Comment: Doesn't look like it's supported in 9.3 `ERROR 999999: Error executing function.Workspace type is invalid`. I think [these](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgiSDEsktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=ListDatasets_method) are the types I'm limited to.

Comment: @AndyArismendi - Sorry, looked only at the tags and saw arcpy, didn't notice the 9.3 gp in the code. Edited tags to reflect proper version of ArcGIS. See my edit about DatasetType

Comment: No problem, the `arcgisscripting` tag only has 2 followers where the `arcpy` tag has 31. I figured I might get some more eyeballs with the arcpy tag. Sorry for the confusion.